# App is crashing upon release and cannot get stacktrace from google play

Tags: android, google-play, flutter

So my apps apk works fine on debug, as soon as i put this out for release, my app can be installed but will crash immediately upon opening the app.  I have no way of finding the error using a stacktrace because google play only gives me something like this under my crashes tab,

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> myapp.mobile.app <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000001cd66  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
  #01  pc 000000000005b861  /data/app/myapp.mobile.app-NMGEC5MygxTSkiehEoUA7A==/lib/arm/libflutter.so
  #02  pc 000000000004ff59  /data/app/myapp.mobile.app-NMGEC5MygxTSkiehEoUA7A==/lib/arm/libflutter.so (JNI_OnLoad+72)
  #03  pc 0000000000234d79  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+2324)
  #04  pc 0000000000002f5b  /system/lib/libopenjdkjvm.so (JVM_NativeLoad+230)
  #05  pc 000000000010c733  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad [DEDUPED]+130)
  #06  pc 000000000016708b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0+146)
  #07  pc 000000000016b94f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.System.loadLibrary+86)
  #08  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #09  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #10  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #11  pc 00000000001e5ae9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+236)
  #12  pc 00000000001e05d7  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+814)
  #13  pc 00000000003e27af  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
  #14  pc 0000000000400494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #15  pc 0000000000008ed4  /data/app/myapp.mobile.app-NMGEC5MygxTSkiehEoUA7A==/oat/arm/base.vdex (io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.a+80)
  #16  pc 00000000001c4d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2471763592+378)
  #17  pc 00000000001c9439  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+152)
  #18  pc 00000000001e05bf  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+790)
  #19  pc 00000000003e27af  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
  #20  pc 0000000000400494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #21  pc 0000000000008e6a  /data/app/myapp.mobile.app-NMGEC5MygxTSkiehEoUA7A==/oat/arm/base.vdex (io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.a+10)
  #22  pc 00000000001c4d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2471763592+378)
  #23  pc 00000000001c937f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
  #24  pc 00000000003d52b9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+880)
  #25  pc 0000000000411aff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
  #26  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #27  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #28  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #29  pc 00000000001e5ae9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+236)
  #30  pc 00000000001e05d7  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+814)
  #31  pc 00000000003e27af  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
  #32  pc 0000000000400494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #33  pc 0000000000007b8a  /data/app/myapp.mobile.app-NMGEC5MygxTSkiehEoUA7A==/oat/arm/base.vdex (io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication.onCreate+6)
  #34  pc 00000000001c4d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2471763592+378)
  #35  pc 00000000001c937f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
  #36  pc 00000000003d52b9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+880)
  #37  pc 0000000000411aff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
  #38  pc 000000000067a899  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate+40)
  #39  pc 000000000075a4bb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+6626)
  #40  pc 0000000000756435  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+5788)
  #41  pc 000000000090e329  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+136)
  #42  pc 0000000000910a23  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1162)
  #43  pc 000000000075f6b3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+674)
  #44  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #45  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #46  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #47  pc 0000000000347ac5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #48  pc 0000000000348f15  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1024)
  #49  pc 00000000002fb0c5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+40)
  #50  pc 000000000011226f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
  #51  pc 0000000000a0a56b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+114)
  #52  pc 0000000000a10455  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2836)
  #53  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #54  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #55  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #56  pc 0000000000347ac5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #57  pc 00000000003478ef  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+310)
  #58  pc 000000000028eb11  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+444)
  #59  pc 000000000006c93b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+30)
  #60  pc 000000000006eb93  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+458)
  #61  pc 0000000000001989  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+728)
  #62  pc 000000000008ae6d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
  #63  pc 000000000000166f  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+38)
  #64  pc 0000000000000306  <anonymous>
```

this doesn't mean anything to me, i followed directions from deployment from here https://flutter.io/android-release/, and tried to go back over and over again to figure out the issue with the release.

I'm going to run you through the non-obvious steps i took and hopefully i can get a reason as to why my app is crashing

1. Remove the android.permission.INTERNET if the app doesnt require the internet;

   - I left this in because i have a link on my app that i want people to click on and be led to the browser; otherwise this app needs no internet connection at all, and should be able to operate without the internet.  I don't know if i have to keep this or not, so i kept it.
2. Versioning of minSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion.

   - I wasnt quite sure of what to do here.  My SDK's on android studio include oreo(27) and 28, so i put a min of 16 and target of 28 and also put the compileSDK at 28.
3. Proguard rules

   - I have a flutter plugin for sqlite that is "package:sqflite/sqflite.dart", and was wondering if these rules will include the sqlite flutter plugin i have (which it seems like it does)

i have this in my proguard-rules.pro

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

I do not have an android device to see the crash for myself, and every emulator i used with google play (nexus 5, api 27, android 8.1) and also one with api 28, says that the app isn't compatible with device in the google play store.  So i cannot recreate it in my emulators.

It has crashed on all of my testers phones running android 9

If any of this makes sense to you as to why it is crashing please let me know, if not how can i get a stacktrace of my crash so i can continue to figure out why this is happening.

Comment if you need to see anymore of my files, thank you

build.gradle (android only)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp.mobile.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "Beta."
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Did you try installing the release version from Android Studio, where it is easier to debug it?

Comment: i don't know how to, when i run the app to the emulator it always builds app-debug.apk and installs app.apk.  when i try to click and drag app-release.apk into the emulator it says "could not parse error string"

Comment: in Android Studio, usually on the left-hand side, there is a `BuildVariants` section where you can (usually) switch between `debug` and `release`. Switch to `release` and then run the app as you normally would.

Comment: okay, so i don't have anything under BuildVariants, is that something i would have to make myself?

Comment: Do you have different build types configured in your `build.gradle`? They are usually listed there.

Comment: I only have one build type configured and it is for release